# Can't access any repository on ParrotOS

Tags: networking, package-management, vmware, parrotsec

I am running this VM on VMware and have never had this many issues. I have internet access. I have searched through forums for the past two days trying to find any solution but none seem to be working for me.

Here is what I am getting:

```
┌─[✗]─[USER@Parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lts InRelease
Ign:2 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot InRelease                                                      
Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian ara InRelease                                             
Ign:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports InRelease                                
Ign:5 https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot parrot-security InRelease                          
Ign:6 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates InRelease                                                          
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian ara Release                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.84.18.34 443]
Err:8 http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.186.132 80]
Ign:9 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports InRelease                                
Ign:1 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lts InRelease                      
Err:10 http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.186.132 80]
Ign:2 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot InRelease                                                 
Ign:11 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy InRelease                                             
Ign:12 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot parrot-security InRelease   
Ign:13 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian wheezy-proposed-updates InRelease
Ign:9 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports InRelease
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome!  Would you mind seeing if `ping 8.8.8.8` works?

Comment: ara is not a valid debian distribution so isn't available in this line `Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian ara Release` . Then wheezy is so old it has been moved to https://archive.debian.org/debian/ . You have yet to provide what exactly isn't working. This shows a repository configuration error but doesn't show a network error.

Comment: If you want to install docker, install it from ParrotOS packages: https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/pool/main/d/docker.io/ .